# What is necessity in modal logic?

Tags: modal-logic

I understand that something that is necessary must exist. However, what is the exact definition of necessity?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the forum. Very broadly, *p* is necessary in world *w* iff *p* is true in all worlds that *w* can access (where the definition of accessibility differs from modal system to system). Consequently, an object exists necessarily (as far as *w* is concerned) iff it exists in all worlds that *w* can access. (How existence across worlds is understood exactly, is more a matter of metaphysics and less a matter of modal logic.) For more details, have a look at e.g. this article: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/

Comment: I understand what you have said; however, what, exactly, is necessity? Perhaps it could be understand by contrasting it with contingency? And thank you for your answer.

Comment: I’m not entirely sure what type of answer you are looking for, apart from the formal definition. Do you mean ‘How is the necessity operator *interpreted*’, i.e., are you asking about the semantics of modal logic? Apart from that, I suppose one could say that necessity and contingency are different modes of being true. Perhaps it helps to think of the temporal analog: ‘necessarily, *p*’ is a bit like ‘always, *p*’.

Comment: Maybe giving an example, and contrasting it with something which is possible or impossible might help CMK?

Comment: Mark, you used "necessary" in the definition of "necessity"; I believe that that is where the misunderstanding arises.                                                                                                   I was told that if something is necessary, it must exist. If something is contingent, it's existence is dependent upon certain conditions. Is this true? Thank you both.

Comment: We must distinguish between *sentences* that are necessarily *true*, and *objects* that necessarily *exist*. (I was mostly talking about the former.) Most would agree that ‘2 is even’ is necessarily true. However, it’s less clear that an object exists that is necessarily even; nor is it clear that an object necessarily exists that is even. Quine’s ‘Three grades of modal involvement’ is a great starting point for this debate. Also, have a look at this article about necessary beings: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/god-necessary-being/  Tim Mawson’s ‘Belief in God’ discusses God's necessity.

Comment: @MarkOxford Thank you for your answer and for the links. Are the definitions that I proposed for necessary and contingent things correct though?

Comment: Sure – but what does it mean that one thing *depends on* another for its existence? Perhaps: if my mom hadn’t existed, I wouldn’t have existed, either; so, my existence depends on hers. And: if I hadn’t existed, you’d still have existed; so, you don’t depend on me. Problem: necessary objects depending on another – e.g. numbers on God. Compare ‘If God hadn’t existed, numbers wouldn’t have existed, either’ to ‘If numbers hadn’t existed, God wouldn’t have existed, either’. Both are true if one is, whence God depends on numbers – contrary to what philosophers of religion might want to say.

Comment: @MarkOxford I understand what you are saying. Does this mean that my definition of contingency is correct? Also, unrelated to the topic in a way, how would God's existence be dependent upon the existence of numbers because the existence of numbers is dependent upon the existence of God?

Comment: That’s exactly the point: we *don’t* want God’s existence to depend on the existence of numbers. However, if we define necessary existence using counterfactuals, as I described in the previous comment, then that definition arguably implies that God’s existence depends on the existence of numbers. So, we must either change the definition (and your definition of contingency along with it) or else find another way to break the symmetry. Have a look at the Stanford article (https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/god-necessary-being/). It discusses exactly this problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68675/discussion-between-markoxford-and-cmk).

Comment: @MarkOxford Thank you for your reply. I have read part of the Stanford article, and I believe that it has answered some of my questions and will likely answer the rest also. Thank you again.

Comment: 'Something' in the original question is unclear (as I think are some of the comments) between a proposition or statement's being true in all possible worlds, and an event's, an object's or a state of affairs existing necessarily (e.g. God). Don't we need to talk separately about necessary truth and necessary existence ?

Comment: @GeoffreyThomas I agree.

Answer (score 2):

Necessity means that the truth of a proposition follows in **ALL** possible worlds consequent to that proposition.

This is contrasted with Possibility which means that the truth of a proposition follows in **SOME** world consequent to the initial frame of reference.

---

As MarkOxford linked above, please see this article for further elucidation: https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-modal/

Comment: Thank you. How would you describe what makes something necessary and what something else merely possible? And is possible another word for contingent?

Comment: I imagine, the state of affairs dictates what is Necessary and what is Possible, but your question certainly shines a light on my ignorance--I do not know what it is about the elements/features of states of affairs that "makes something necessary". Is it possible that a thing simply just IS necessary, IS NOT necessary, or is just not the kind of thing that it makes sense to talk about as being necessary or not?

Comment: I understand. I always thought that a contingent entity was one that required the existence of something else to exist. Without that thing, the contingent entity would not exist. That was just based on one dictionary definition of contingency. 

A necessary entity could be one that does not depend on the exist of anything else to exist, and so must exist. That doesn't make much sense, though. 

These are just my ideas, and are not generally accepted it seems. I haven't seen any definition of these things that are generally accepted. Thanks for your insight.

Comment: @CMK: Well, it sort of depends whether you want to use Kripke's definition of possible worlds, which is fairly standard (basically, "a possible world is a set of predicates and truth values"), or something more exotic like Lewis's modal realism and counterpart theory (basically, "a possible world is a parallel universe that really exists").

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you are asking for is a *reductive* analysis of necessity -- one that doesn't use cognate notions such as possibility or possible worlds in its analysis.

One way to go about seeking such an analysis is by accepting the definition in terms of possible worlds that others have mentioned, but then proceeding to give an analysis of what possible worlds are (which doesn't itself appeal to the notion of necessity).

The best known attempt to do this is David Lewis' in *On the Plurality of Worlds*. That's also probably a good source for learning about other approaches. Needless to say, it's very controversial whether any of these approaches succeed - many philosophers think they don't, but think that modal logic is useful anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Saul Kripke provides a straightforward mathematical definition of necessity and possibility:

There is a set of (mathematical) objects called "[possible worlds](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/possible-worlds/)."  Each world assigns[1] truth values to all statements of first-order logic [whose predicates and operands we care about](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_of_discourse), is internally consistent (does not entail any contradictions), but it may disagree with other worlds.  Additionally, there is a [binary relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) between possible worlds called the "accessibility relation."  We may impose requirements on this relation, and in particular we often require it to be reflexive (but not always; see for example [deontic logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deontic_logic)).

Then the necessity (box) operator means "the enclosed statement is satisfied in every world reachable from the current world."  The possibility operator is defined as the dual of the necessity operator (i.e. read diamond as "¬☐¬"), and boxes and diamonds may nest arbitrarily.  So, for example, ☐☐A means "A is satisfied in every world which is two steps away from the current world via the accessibility relation."  Statements are usually considered "true" if they are satisfied in every world.  In Kripke's formulation, no particular world is distinguished as "the actual world," but to do so may be philosophically desirable.

The requirements we impose on the accessibility relation can be translated into axioms about the behavior of the box operator.  For example, if the relation is reflexive, then the axiom ☐A → A is produced, which we usually abbreviate as axiom T.  More colloquially, "anything that is necessarily true is true."

Every modal logic which adheres to the above mathematical structure must at least admit axiom K, which is ☐(P → Q) → (☐P → ☐Q) (If P necessarily implies Q, then the necessity of P implies the necessity of Q).  Every modal logic must also admit axiom N, which states that all tautologies or theorems are necessary (that is, if A follows from the axioms we are using, then ☐A is also a theorem, because A must be true in every world or it would create a contradiction).

In many cases, modal logic is used for purposes other than possibility and necessity.  It retains the same mathematical structure, but the box and diamond are reinterpreted, for example as "It is ethically permissible/obligatory that X" in deontic logic.  So when discussing modal logic generally, we should be careful not to read ☐A as "necessarily A" unless we're sure of our logical context.

This definition is not universally accepted.  In particular, David Lewis offers a wildly different account of possible worlds as "real places" that just happen to be physically inaccessible to us (like parallel universes).  He then goes on to develop a theory of "counterparts" as an alternative to [transworld identity](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/identity-transworld/), which he dislikes (broadly, this is the idea that P(x) may refer to the "same x" in multiple different worlds, which seems problematic if worlds are interpreted as literal places rather than as mathematical objects).

[1]: This is a flat lie.  The worlds do not actually assign truth values.  Rather, truth values are assigned by a second binary relation between worlds and modal statements.  This is a subtle distinction, but in some contexts, we want to consider whether a statement is true for every choice of this second relation, rather than just a particular choice.